# Deployed (ie serverside) mysql db is UTF-8 but local version isn't

Tags: mysql, utf-8

At least i think that's the problem.  In my staging and production databases (both on the same server) i have a table with a text field that holds html.  Some of these have web quotes, which are displayed fine.

However, locally i have my development database which is a copy of the staging database (it was copied by taking a dump of the staging db with mysqldump, dropping my local one, then pushing the staging dump file into mysql).  Locally, the webquotes show up as â€œ (for a start webquote) in mysql.

I'm guessing this is because my local database isn't set up properly for utf-8?  How do i find out for sure?  And how do i fix it?

grateful for any advice - max

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `mysql --default-character-set=utf8 [...]` for your local import.